# Get the size/length of an array column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new in Scala programming and this is my question: How to count the number of string for each row? My Dataframe is composed of a single column of Array[String] type.

```
friendsDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [friends: array<string>]
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use the [`size`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) function:

```
val df = Seq((Array("a","b","c"), 2), (Array("a"), 4)).toDF("friends", "id")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [friends: array<string>, id: int]

df.select(size($"friends").as("no_of_friends")).show
+-------------+
|no_of_friends|
+-------------+   
|            3|
|            1|
+-------------+
```

---

To add as a new column:

```
df.withColumn("no_of_friends", size($"friends")).show
+---------+---+-------------+
|  friends| id|no_of_friends|
+---------+---+-------------+
|[a, b, c]|  2|            3|
|      [a]|  4|            1|
+---------+---+-------------+
```

Comment: For an empty array, size is also 1.

Comment: @aloplop85 No. An empty array has a size of 0. Something like `[""]` is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `size` function and that would give you the number of elements in the array. There is only issue as pointed by @aloplop85 that for an empty array, it gives you value of 1 and that is correct because empty string is also considered as a value in an array but if you want to get around this for your use case where you want the size to be zero if the array has one value and that is also empty string.

```
//source data
val df = Seq((Array("a","b","c"), 2), (Array("a"), 4),(Array(""),6)).toDF("friends", "id")
//check the size of the array and see if it 1 and first element is empty string then set value to 0
val df1 = df.withColumn("no_of_friends",when(size(col("friends")) === 1 && col("friends")(0) === "" , lit(0)).otherwise(size(col("friends")) ))
```

You can verify the output as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*data.select( length($"columnaname"))*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).