# Counting instaces of values across lists within a single column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, counter

I have a PySpark dataframe where 1 column consists of lists of strings. I would like to count the number of instances of each element within each list of strings across all rows. Pseudocode :

```
counter = Counter()
for attr_list in df['attr_list']:
   counter.update(attr_list)
```

Another way of doing this would be to concatenate all of the lists across all rows and build a counter out of the single huge list. Is there an efficient way to do this in PySpark?

Correct output would be a single `collections.Counter()` object populated with the number of occurrences of each item in all of the lists across all columns, i.e. if for a given column, row 1 has the list `['a', 'b', 'c']` and row 2 has the list `['b', 'c', 'd']`, we would get a counter that looks like `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}`.

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the size/length of an array column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098573/get-the-size-length-of-an-array-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the **`elements`** that you have to count, then you can use this with **`spark2.4+.`** and it will be really fast.( using **`higher order function filter`** and **`structs`**)

```
df.show()

#+------------+
#|    atr_list|
#+------------+
#|[a, b, b, c]|
#|   [b, c, d]|
#+------------+

elements=['a','b','c','d']

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
collected=df.withColumn("struct", F.struct(*[(F.struct(F.expr("size(filter(atr_list,x->x={}))"\
                                                    .format("'"+y+"'"))).alias(y)) for y in elements]))\
            .select(*[F.sum(F.col("struct.{}.col1".format(x))).alias(x) for x in elements])\
            .collect()[0]

{elements[i]: [x for x in collected][i] for i in range(len(elements))}
```

`Out: {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}`

2nd Method, using **`transform, aggregate, explode and groupby`**( does not require elements to be specified):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

a=df.withColumn("atr", F.expr("""transform(array_distinct(atr_list),x->aggregate(atr_list,0,(acc,y)->\
                               IF(y=x, acc+1,acc)))"""))\
  .withColumn("zip", F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.array_distinct("atr_list"),("atr"))))\
  .select("zip.*").withColumnRenamed("0","elements")\
  .groupBy("elements").agg(F.sum("atr").alias("sum"))\
  .collect()

{a[i][0]: a[i][1] for i in range(len(a))}
```

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately in this situation there are over 3000 elements, that's why I was hoping to use something akin to a python Counter() dict. Using a hash table to increment variables accessed using only the list elements in the given row's like should be much faster than iterating once for every element.

Comment: I disagree, the above code is not iterating, it is happening at once under the hood, and there is no fast way of using something like counter() dict in spark . Have u tried putting all your 3000 distinct elements in the elements list as above and run the code ?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for the solution. I had some very interesting results. I was doing this by just doing an rdd.collect() on the attribute column and then running through the list updating a counter dict one by one. When doing this, it's actually the rdd.collect() that takes the most time. Your solution is much faster, however the two solutions scale in very different ways. I tested a 10k sample and a 50k sample. The method with the counter dict and collect() took 700 and 713 seconds respectively for each sample. Your method took 31 seconds and 48 seconds respectively. Thanks!

Comment: @theShmoo no problem and thanks for the feedback as i was curious about the speed. and if u had much bigger data, the difference in speed would be much bigger too

Answer (score 1):

One option by converting to RDD's is to merge all the arrays into one and then using a `Counter` object on it.

```
from collections import Counter
all_lists = df.select('listCol').rdd
print(Counter(all_lists.map(lambda x: [i for i in x[0]]).reduce(lambda x,y: x+y)))
```

Another option with `explode` and `groupBy` and merging the result to a `dictionary`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
explode_df = df.withColumn('exploded_list',explode(df.listCol))
counts = explode_df.groupBy('exploded_list').count()
counts_tuple = counts.rdd.reduce(lambda a,b : a+b)
print({counts_tuple[i]:counts_tuple[i+1] for i in range(0,len(counts_tuple)-1,2)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `distinct` and `flatMap` method of rdd, for this just convert the column into and rdd and do these operations.

```
counter = (df
           .select("attr_list")
           .rdd
           # join all strings in the list and then split to get each word
           .map(lambda x: " ".join(x).split(" ")) 
           .flatMap(lambda x: x)
           # make a tuple for each word so later it can be grouped by to get its frequency count
           .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
           .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
           .collectAsMap())
```